# Where Fallout 3 Oasis might be in real life?

Tags: fallout

I happen to live near Bethesda MD and I've looked online to find any clue where Oasis (in Fallout 3) might be and take a visit but I haven't been able to find any solid evidence of the location in real life. It appears to me it could be somewhere north of Germantown, and west of Olney, next to a highway so it could be Montgomery Village.
Any idea, my fellow wastelanders?

Comment: Are you asking in-universe where it is or what?

Comment: @Mithrandir in real life, not in game. I know Fallout 3 'happened' in the DC metro area and a lot of the locations are real so I just wonder where Bethesda studio got the idea of Oasis from. Must be a beautiful place.

Comment: So more specifically, your question is whether it was based on a real-life location as opposed to one made out of whole cloth?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots that's not exactly my question but close. Assuming they created the place based on a real life location, I'm asking where that place might be. A lot of the locations in Fallout 3 are actually based on real life locations. That's why I used "might be".

Comment: {nods} Well, as stated above, it would be roughly around Montgomery Village. https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1DuilfvNcMvhMosMjyZBL6Vgvjp4&hl=en_US&ll=39.16067213688282%2C-77.17272165289&z=14 The nearest mention of a mine I've found is Chrome Mine Rd (presumably named after a nearby mine that may or may not exist anymore), but that's further east towards Gaithersberg, halfway to Vault 92.

Comment: I lived in the area long ago and what I remember is very close to where I lived were forests, even with a stream. I suspect all that land is developed now.